# Angular 2 - $http catch and stop a redirect

Tags: angular

I am hitting an external API with GET that, if user is unauthenticated, it will return a redirect to a login page.  Well the issue is that $http automatically follows the redirect url instead of allowing me to handle it.  So what is happening is that it hits the first url, then right away  hits the redirect url which in turn returns an error because the redirect is supposed to be loaded via the browser, not via ajax.

So I was wondering if there is a way to catch and stop a redirect on an ajax call?

Here is the requested example:

```
this.http
  .get(url)
  .map((response:Response) => {
    return response.json() : response;
  })
  .finally(() => this.onComplete())
  .subscribe(
    (data:any) => this.onSuccess(data),
    (error:Error) => this.onError(error)
  ));
```

So basically what is happening is the following in the network tab:

1. It calls original url: url.com/original
2. Then it automatically calls the redirect URL via get: url.com/newUrl
3. The code calls onSuccess and gives me the response of the redirect which is just html.

So if I can't change the API to not do redirect when it is an AJAX request, is there anything I can do on the angular side to solve it?

Comment: can you add some example?

Comment: @DoronBrikman Sorry for late reply, I edited description with example you requested.